# is there a way to pass derived classes as a condition in an if-else statement?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have a virtual function that I want to create that uses derived classes as conditions. So in the code below, `class Video_Games` will have the variable `shipcost` be 4.99. And so and so forth for Phones, Sausages and Albums. How, if at all, can I pass classes through as a condition in an if-else statement that is within a virtual function inside the big class called "Package"? I would like to do that so that I can call on `shipcost` in a printed receipt that knows exactly how to display the proper shipping for each class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Package
{
protected:
    string name_and_address = "?";

    double cost = 0.0;
    double discount = 0.0;
    double discount_rate = 0.0;

    bool overnight_delivery = false;
    bool insured = false;

    string package_contents = "?";

    double shipcost = 0.0;

public:
    Package() {};
    ~Package() {};

protected:
    virtual double calculate_cost() = 0;

    virtual double shipping_cost()
    {
        if (class Video_Games :public Package) //getting error here that says class or struct definition is missing 
            shipcost = 4.99;
        else if (class Genius_Phone :public Package) //getting error here that says class or struct definition is missing 
            shipcost = 25.00;
        else if (class Sausage :public Package) //getting error here that says class or struct definition is missing 
            shipcost = 9.00;
        else
            shipcost = 50.00;

        return shipcost;
    }

    virtual double calculate_discount()
    {
        if (cost > 1000)
            discount_rate = 0.033;
        else if (cost > 500)
            discount_rate = 0.028;
        else if (cost > 200)
            discount_rate = 0.024;
        else
            discount_rate = 0.019;

        return cost * discount_rate;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Package &Package_Instance)
    {
        return Package_Instance.print(out);
    }



    ostream& print(ostream& out) const
    {
        chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
        time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now + chrono::hours(24));

        chrono::system_clock::time_point now2 = chrono::system_clock::now();
        time_t now2_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now2 + chrono::hours(72));

        cout << "       *** BILL FOR GOODS ***\n";
        cout << "Customer: " << endl << endl;
        cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed;
        cout << name_and_address << endl;
        cout << (overnight_delivery ? (put_time(localtime(&now_c), "Expected Arrival Date: %F")) : put_time(localtime(&now2_c), "Expected Arrival Date: %F")) << endl << endl;
        cout << package_contents << endl;
        cout << (insured ? "{INSURED}\n" : "{NOT INSURED}\n");
        cout << (overnight_delivery ? "Expedited Shipping\n" : "Standard Shipping\n");
        cout << shipcost << endl; //This is where I want the shipcost to display the dollar amount that corresponds directly to the type of shipcost used for each derived class. So video games would be 4.99, albums would be 50.00 etc. etc. etc. 
        cout << "Total Cost is: $" << cost << endl;
        cout << "Discount Percentage is: " << discount_rate * 100 << "%" << " for a discount of $" << discount << endl;
        cout << "Total Cost after discount is $" << cost - discount << endl << endl;

        return out;
    }
};

class Video_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;

public:
    Video_Games(string location, int number_of_games, bool express, bool insurance)
    {
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string(num_games) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();
        shipcost = shipping_cost();
    }

    ~Video_Games() {};

protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += shipcost; } //this would be 4.99, and so and so forth for the rest of the classes (not edited yet, but I will edito those when I can nail this baby down). 
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.06; }

        return cost;
    }
};

class Genius_Phone :public Package
{
private:
    int num_phones = 0;
    int num_cases = 0;
public:
    Genius_Phone(string location, int number_of_phones, bool express, bool insurance, int number_of_cases)
    {
        num_phones = number_of_phones;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;
        num_cases = number_of_cases;

        package_contents = to_string(num_phones) + " Genius Phone(s), " +
            (num_cases > 0 ? "and " + to_string(num_cases) + " cases " : "");

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();
    }

    ~Genius_Phone() {};
protected:
    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_phones * 699.99 + num_cases * 24.99;
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += 25.00; }
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.11; }

        return cost;
    }
};

class Sausage :public Package
{
private:
    int num_Hot_Dogs = 0;
    int num_Condiments = 0;
    int num_Hot_Dog_Buns = 0;
public:
    Sausage(string location, int hotdogs, bool express, bool insurance, int condiments, int buns)
    {
        num_Hot_Dogs = hotdogs;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;
        num_Condiments = condiments;
        num_Hot_Dog_Buns = buns;

        package_contents = to_string(num_Hot_Dogs) + " Hot Dog(s), " +
            (num_Condiments > 0 ? to_string(num_Condiments) + " Condiment(s) " : "") +
            (num_Hot_Dog_Buns > 0 ? "and " + to_string(num_Hot_Dog_Buns) + " Hot Dog Bun(s) " : "");

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();
    }

    ~Sausage() {};
protected:
    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_Hot_Dogs * 5.99 + num_Hot_Dog_Buns * 1.29 + num_Condiments * 0.79;
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += 9.00; }
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.03; }

        return cost;
    }
};

class Albums :public Package
{
private:
    int num_albums = 0;
    int limited_edition = 0;
    int signed_vinyl = 0;
public:
    Albums(string location, int vinyls, bool express, bool insurance, int limited, int signature)
    {
        num_albums = vinyls;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;
        limited_edition = limited;
        signed_vinyl = signature;

        package_contents = to_string(num_albums) + " Sia Vinyl Record(s), " +
            (limited_edition > 0 ? to_string(limited_edition) + " Limited Edition Version(s) " : "") +
            (signed_vinyl > 0 ? "and " + to_string(signed_vinyl) + " Signed by Sia herself " : "");

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();
    }

    ~Albums() {};
protected:
    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_albums * 19.99 + signed_vinyl * 79.99 + limited_edition * 29.99;
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += 50.00; }
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.25; }

        return cost;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Video_Games a("Link LINK\nKokiri Forest\nKyoto, JAPAN 77547\n", 4, true, false);
    cout << a;

    Genius_Phone b("Ada LOVELACE\n1010 Binary Street\nLondon, ENGLAND 67859\n", 1, true, false, 2);
    cout << b;

    Sausage c("Princess Anna\n2013 Disney Road\nArendelle, ALASKA 92684\n", 350, false, true, 351, 4);
    cout << c;

    Albums d("David,\n1326 90th Drive NE\nEverett, WASHINGTON 98205\n", 4, false, true, 2, 1);
    cout << d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't the classes have a method that returns the cost?!

Comment: Double dispatching would solve the issue.

Comment: How would I double dispatch? That sounds like an advanced technique.

Comment: @polymorphism of which type is part `shipping_cost`? it's virtual, but no classes around it.

Comment: @skypjack I have edited my answer to include the whole code set so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @polymorphism `shipping_cost` is virtual. simply implement it in the base class and return the default value, then override it when needed in the derived classes.

Comment: how do I implement it in the base class and return the default value?

Comment: @polymorphism see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly then, you need to use a function in base class which will call functions in derived class. In such a case Design Pattern: Template Method can be used.

```
class Package
{
    public:
        virtual double get_shipping_cost() = 0;
        void PrintReceipt()
        {
            //some calulations

            double shipcost = get_shipping_cost();

            //use shipcost in printing the receipt      
        }
};

class Video_Games : public Package
{
    public:

    double get_shipping_cost()
    {
        return 4.99;
    }   
};

class Phones : public Package
{
    public:

    double get_shipping_cost()
    {
        return 6.78;
    }   
};

// now you can print receipt as follows:
Package *pPackage = new Video_Games();
pPackage->PrintReceipt();
//OR
Video_Games a(....);
a.PrintReceipt();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use shipcost as a variable that can be used to across all package types and printed out inside the format I've laid out inside the big class Package (you can see it in my code) is there a way to get shipcost in there?

Comment: [1]If `shipcost` is a variable in base class then you can initialize it in every derived class constructor. [2] You can get `shipcost` dynamically depending upon object via method as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need derived classes here at all.

`Package` can just be initialised from values calculated for each category of object. Just in the example here I would have `VideoGames` et al be free functions that return `Package`s.

Each would be something like

```
Package VideoGames(string name_and_address, int number_of_games, bool express, bool insured)
{
    string contents = to_string(number_of_games) + " Video Game(s)";
    double subtotal = number_of_games * 19.99;
    double shipping = 4.99;
    double insurance_rate = 1.06
    return Package(name_and_address, contents, subtotal, express, shipping, insured, insurance_rate);
}
```

And `Package` would be filled out from those parameters

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking for can be accomplished using `dynamic_cast`, eg:

```
class Package
{
    ...
    double shipping_cost();
    ...
};

class Video_Games : public Package { ... };

class Genius_Phone : public Package { ... };

class Sausage : public Package { ... };

...

double Package::shipping_cost()
{
    if (dynamic_cast<Video_Games*>(this) != NULL)
        return 4.99;
    if (dynamic_cast<Genius_Phone*>(this) != NULL)
        return 25.00;
    if (dynamic_cast<Sausage*>(this) != NULL)
        return 9.00;
    ...
    return 50.00;
}
```

However, your design is wrong and very inflexible.  As you add more classes, you have to keep adding more `if` statements.  This slows the code down over time, as `dynamic_cast` invokes a  runtime lookup and thus has some overhead to it.

Use polymorphism the way it is meant to be used.  All functionality that is common across derived classes should be in the base class. Anything the base class needs that is type-specific should be exposed as virtual methods that can be overriden in the derived classes.

Try something more like this:

```
class Package
{
protected:
    string name_and_address;
    string package_contents;
    bool overnight_delivery;
    bool is_insured;

public:
   Package(string location, bool express, bool insured)
        : name_and_address(location), overnight_delivery(express), is_insured(insured)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Package() {}

    virtual double price() const = 0;

    static double discount_rate(double cost) const
    {
        if (cost > 1000)
            return 0.033;
        if (cost > 500)
            return 0.028;
        if (cost > 200)
            return 0.024;
        return 0.019;
    }

    virtual double shipping_cost() const
    {
        return 50.00;
    }

    virtual double insurance_rate() const
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    double calculate_cost() const
    {
        double cost = price();
        if (overnight_delivery)
            cost += shipping_cost();
        if (is_insured)
            cost *= insurance_rate();
        return cost;
    }

    void print(ostream& out) const
    {
        chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
        time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now + chrono::hours(24));
        chrono::system_clock::time_point now2 = chrono::system_clock::now();
        time_t now2_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now2 + chrono::hours(72));

        out << " *** BILL FOR GOODS ***" << endl;
        out << "Customer: " << endl << endl;
        out << name_and_address << endl;
        out << (overnight_delivery ? (put_time(localtime(&now_c), "Expected Arrival Date: %F")) : put_time(localtime(&now2_c), "Expected Arrival Date: %F")) << endl << endl;
        out << package_contents << endl;
        out << (is_insured ? "{INSURED}" : "{NOT INSURED}") << endl;
        out << (overnight_delivery ? "Expedited Shipping" : "Standard Shipping") << endl;

        double cost = calculate_cost();
        double rate = discount_rate(cost);
        double discount = cost * rate;

        out << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed;
        out << "Shipping: $" << shipping_cost() << endl;
        out << "Total Cost is: $" << cost << endl;
        out << "Discount Percentage is: " << rate * 100 << "%" << " for a discount of $" << discount << endl;
        out << "Total Cost after discount is $" << cost - discount << endl << endl;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Package &Package_Instance)
{
    Package_Instance.print(out);
    return out;
}

class Video_Games : public Package
{
private:
    int num_games;

public:
    Video_Games(string location, int number_of_games, bool express, bool insured)
        : Package(location, express, insured), num_games(number_of_games)
    {
        package_contents = to_string(num_games) + " Video Game(s)";
    }

    virtual double price() const
    {
        return num_games * 19.99;
    }

    virtual double shipping_cost() const
    {
        return 4.99;
    }

    virtual double insurance_rate() const
    {
        return 1.06;
    }
};

class Genius_Phone : public Package
{
private:
    int num_phones;
    int num_cases;

public:
    Genius_Phone(string location, int number_of_phones, bool express, bool insured, int number_of_cases)
        : Package(location, express, insured), num_phones(number_of_phones), num_cases(number_of_cases)
    {
        package_contents = to_string(num_phones) + " Genius Phone(s), " + (num_cases > 0 ? "and " + to_string(num_cases) + " cases " : "");
    }

    virtual double price() const
    {
        return (num_phones * 699.99) + (num_cases * 24.99);
    }

    virtual double shipping_cost() const
    {
        return 25.00;
    }

    virtual double insurance_rate() const
    {
        return 1.11;
    }
};

class Sausage : public Package
{
private:
    int num_Hot_Dogs;
    int num_Condiments;
    int num_Hot_Dog_Buns; 

public:
    Sausage(string location, int hotdogs, bool express, bool insured, int condiments, int buns)
        : Package(location, express, insured), num_Hot_Dogs(hotdogs), num_Condiments(condiments), num_Hot_Dog_Buns(buns)
    {
        package_contents = to_string(num_Hot_Dogs) + " Hot Dog(s), " + (num_Condiments > 0 ? to_string(num_Condiments) + " Condiment(s) " : "") + (num_Hot_Dog_Buns > 0 ? "and " + to_string(num_Hot_Dog_Buns) + " Hot Dog Bun(s) " : "");
    }

    virtual double price() const
    {
        return (num_Hot_Dogs * 5.99) + (num_Hot_Dog_Buns * 1.29) + (num_Condiments * 0.79);
    }

    virtual double shipping_cost() const
    {
        return 9.00;
    }

    virtual double insurance_rate() const
    {
        return 1.03;
    }
};

class Albums : public Package
{
private:
    int num_albums;
    int limited_edition;
    int signed_vinyl;

public:
    Albums(string location, int vinyls, bool express, bool insured, int limited, int signature)
        : Package(location, express, insured), num_albums(vinyls), limited_edition(limited), signed_vinyl(signature)
    {
        package_contents = to_string(num_albums) + " Sia Vinyl Record(s), " + (limited_edition > 0 ? to_string(limited_edition) + " Limited Edition Version(s) " : "") + (signed_vinyl > 0 ? "and " + to_string(signed_vinyl) + " Signed by Sia herself " : "");
    }

    virtual double price() const
    {
        return (num_albums * 19.99) + (signed_vinyl * 79.99) + (limited_edition * 29.99);
    }

    virtual double shipping_cost() const
    {
        return 50.00;
    }

    virtual double insurance_rate() const
    {
        return 1.25;
    }
};
```

Comment: i'm trying to avoid massive overhauls, so i tried dynamic casting, and it says (without red-underline) that there is a syntax error for the class identifiers `Video_Games`, `Genius_Phone` and `Sausage`...not sure why since it's an error happening after i've hit run. Before that there is no redline or error showing.

Comment: @polymorphism sounds like you are not defining those classes before you are trying to use them.

Comment: I'm a little new to dynamic casting, so you'll have to excuse me, but would defining it entail something like: 

`package* pd = new Video_Game();`
`Video_Game py = dynamic_cast<Video_Game*>(this);`
`if (dynamic_cast<Video_Games*>(this))
        return 4.99;`

Comment: i'm not sure if that would work anyways because if i define it it would turn into an object and thus not be able to be pointed to inside a virtual function using dynamic_cast...but i could be off the mark.

Comment: Now that I've defined the classes, I'm getting `-nan(ind)` as a runtime error. So, I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet. Previously, it was returning 50.00 as the cost for video games, which is wrong. It should have been returning 4.99. So I think I'm almost there, but I think it might have to do with the if/else structure. I think your method is sending it straight to the else statement and my attempt to fix it just made it go bonkers.

Comment: I've defined the classes above the virtual function as `class Video_Games {};`...is this the right idea? I'm not sure how to implement this without getting runtime errors.